# Replacement for CHtmlView

Tags: c++, windows, internet-explorer, mfc

Since `CHtmlView` utilizes an Internet Explorer based control (IE), which is no longer supported by Windows, does anyone know what the long term solution for MFC based applications that utilize this control?  Native desktop apps that utilize this technology need a viable migration path.  Microsoft is not forthcoming.  What solutions have you found?

Same question regarding `CHtmlEditCtrl`.

Comment: `CHtmlView` will continue to work just fine even though it has IE under the hood. It will not break. This is confirmed by Microsoft. WebView2 has a lot of missing features and limitations (depending upon how you want to use the control). For me, I have come to a complete standstill for the timebeing on migration. But for you it may be fine.

Comment: FWIW, I have been held up by the way the printing is managed. The printing is forced to the size of the control, this is fine if you have a full screen browser, but when you viewer is part of a dialog .... and the beta Print API that is in dicussion would mean I have to roll my own previewer. Anyway, I digress. Have a look on links provided in the answer.

Comment: @AndrewTruckle  One side effect of the CHtmlView IE is that I have actual web links in my app's HTML that are php scripts that end up being the URL for a specific .pdf document based on a part number passed in to the script.  The PDF ends up being launched in an instance of IE, which in one tab has the .pdf, but sometimes a second (top) tab shows up being the MS "IE is no longer supported, use Edge" message page.  I guess I can change the content of the app's HTML pages that utilizes Edge for that query.  Good to know that CHtmlView(Edit) won't be going away.  I can handle the external links.

Comment: @and *"`CHtmlView` will continue to work just fine even though it has IE under the hood."* - That's a blunt statement. IE is discontinued, and the number of web pages it cannot render grows by the minute. Just an example: Try to pull up [Rust's official package library](https://crates.io/) in IE and see where that gets you. Or [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/), for that matter.

Comment: @IInspectable Agreed.  For my specific situation, I don't use it as a browser, but as a presentation of C++ generated HTML pages containing graphics and links to other internal similar pages or to external web pages.  The external web page links I can tweak my generated HTML to be an internal link that I can process in OnBeforeNavigate2 to launch Edge or whatever documents vs. utilizing default behavior of a standard web URL of launching IE as external app (which is what I do now).

Comment: @IInspectable fair points. It was something that Microsoft addressed when they said ie was being removed. They specifically said that apps like mine should still work because it uses a special control or whatever. Anyway, for now I stick with CHtmlView until webview2 can actually do what I need.

Comment: @AndrewTruckle You stated "This is confirmed by Microsoft".  Can you link to something that states that?  Not that I don't believe you (it works on Win11), but it would be good to see their "official stance".  When I tried to find anything on MS website, the best I found here https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/how-long-will-chtmlview-of-mfc-be-supported/1428902 and talking about Edge-based CHtmlView here https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Update-MFC-CHtmlView-to-use-Edge-chromiu/1233024?entry=problem&space=62

Comment: Hhhm. What about: https://blogs.windows.com/windowsexperience/2021/05/19/the-future-of-internet-explorer-on-windows-10-is-in-microsoft-edge/where it says "It also does not affect the MSHTML (Trident) engine". Doesn't CHtmlView use that under the hood? Best I could find.

Answer (score 3):

The replacement for `CHtmlView` is [WebView2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/) (unless you're targeting ARM, but then you wouldn't be compiling MFC anyway...).

As for replacing a `CHtmlEditCtrl`, there is no support in WebView2 for accessing the DOM through the public API (see [GitHub issue](https://github.com/MicrosoftEdge/WebView2Feedback/issues/77)). If you need to access/modify the DOM that would have to be done via script.

Comment: Yes - access to IHTMLDocument2 and related DOM interfaces are also needed.

Comment: That's understood, though... what did you expect? I mean, this has been going on for a decade now, with Microsoft pulling the plug on anything that's not immediately profitable. Windows 10 Mobile? Gone. The UWP? Soon-to-be gone along with it. Zune? Discontinued. The Microsoft Band? Abandoned just two weeks prior to the Band 3 release. If the technology isn't Nadella's "Intelligent Edge" or .NET, and you need it, you're basically screwed. Sorry, I'm just the messenger here.